# How to keep trailing zeroes in formatting decimal numbers?

Tags: vba, excel, formatting, number-formatting

Suppose that I have the following numbers in Notepad:

```
1.19
0.040
10.1123
23.110
21.223
2.35456
4.0
10234.0009
456798.7500
123
34.560
40060
33.7876
```

If I copy the numbers and paste them in Excel, the numbers will change to this:

```
1.19
0.04
10.1123
23.11
21.223
2.35456
4
10234.0009
456798.75
123
34.56
40060
33.7876
```

I want to copy-paste the numbers without changing their original format, for example:

- 0.040, not 0.04
- 4.0, not 4
- 456798.7500, not 456798.75

I'm aware that I can use conditional formatting like

```
If condition_1 Then
   Cells(...).NumberFormat = "0.00"

ElseIf condition_2 Then
   Cells(...).NumberFormat = "0.000"

...

Else
   result_else

End If
```

or use **Select ... Case Statement**, but the problems with these methods are:

1. The code can be lengthy and looks messy.
2. If the numbers change, then the conditionals must change, too.

So my question is:

> How to make Excel not truncate the zeroes at the end of decimal numbers?

I want to keep the values as numbers, **not** text.

This kind of representation does matter in financial data for example: foreign exchange or currency rate.

Comment: Before pasting, you need to change the column format to Text.

Comment: What conditions would you use, if you were to use conditional formatting?

Comment: @NanAvanIllai I've just realized that so I edit my question. I add **P.S.**

Comment: Don't change the true numbers to text-that-looks-like-a-number.Never, never, never. What other column has an identifier that can determine what the number format should be? Can you provide 3-5 examples?

Comment: Why do you need the trailing 0's (which do not appear to provide any information, as numbers)?

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀, please go through this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/269370

Comment: @ScottHunter - As I understand the problem (I have some prior knowledge) it is to demonstrate that a currency that should be displayed to a 4 decimal precision is always displayed that way. Unfortunately, other currencies may only demand a 2 decimal precision. The key I believe is the currency identifier.

Comment: @ScottHunter In finance, formatting numbers like this does matter. If I use conditional formatting, I might use `If number_1 > 10 Then ` but this doesn't work for any value of currencies

Comment: I don't understand why does one downvote this since it's kind of representation really matters in finance like foreign exchange data

Comment: @NanAvanIllai That's not what I want. Thanks, though.

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 Apply the shortcut, ALT + H, ANM and change the decimal places as 4

Comment: Anastasiya - if you don't have a column of currency identifiers then the numbers are meaningless anyways. Why are you so reluctant to disclose this **very** important piece of information? (btw, the down-voter probably didn't like being told that number-as-text was a bad idea. have one back+1)

Comment: @Jeeped It's not meaningless to me but applying that kind of conditionals will extend the code like I said in point 1. I'm hoping that user here is able to give me the alternative way, i.e. the simplest and most efficient one. Thanks for the +1, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I place your original data in column **A** *(with your posted formats)* and run this:

```
Sub CopyFull()
    Dim A As Range, B As Range

    Set A = Range("A1:A13")
    Set B = Range("B1:B13")
    A.Copy B
End Sub
```

The copied data items will have the same formats as the originals:

[image]

So if **A9** has a `NumberFormat` of *0.0000*, then so will **B9**.

**EDIT#1:**

If the data started out in an open NotePad process, I would:

1. manually (*or programmatically*) store the data as a text file (*.txt*)
2. import the text file into a column as **Text**
3. convert each item in the column into a **Number** with a `NumberFormat` consistent with the text format

Comment: See! Finally someone with the answer instead of downvoting my OP without giving any suggestions. Hmm, this is really an interesting answer. But how if the numbers from notepad and then I wanna keep the original formats after pasting them in Excel?

Comment: I answer my own question using your suggestion in **EDIT#1**. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't that mean Gary's student answered it?

Answer (score 2):

If there was any accompanying column with an identifier that could be used to group the numerical values into currency format categories then the problem becomes simple¹.

[image: currency_conditional_before]
                        <sup>Data before running the currencyConditionals sub procedure</sup>

<sub>• EUR should use €, have 3 decimal places and be green

                  • JPN should use ¥, have 4 decimal places and be dark red

                  • GPD should use £, have 0 decimal places and be dark blue

                  • USD should use $, have 2 decimal places and be blue</sub>

Run the code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub currencyConditionals()
    Dim a As Long, aCURRs As Variant, aFRMTS As Variant

    aCURRs = Array("EUR", "JPY", "GBP", "USD")
    aFRMTS = Array("[color10]_([$€-2]* #,##0.000_);[color3]_([$€-2]* (#,##0.000);[color15]_(* -??_);[color46]_(@_)", _
                   "[color9]_([$¥-411]* #,##0.0000_);[color9]_=[$¥-411]* (#,##0.0000);[color15]_(* -??_);[color46]_(@_)", _
                   "[color11]_([$£-809]* #,##0_-;[color11]-[$£-809]* #,##0_-;[color15]_-[$£-809]* -_);[color46]_-@_-", _
                   "[color5]_($* #,##0.00_);[color5]_($* (#,##0.00);[color15]_($* -??_);[color46]_(@_)")

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Offset(1, 5).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
                .FormatConditions.Delete
                For a = LBound(aCURRs) To UBound(aCURRs)
                    With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
                                Formula1:="=$C2=" & Chr(34) & aCURRs(a) & Chr(34))
                        .NumberFormat = aFRMTS(a)
                    End With
                Next a
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: currency_conditional_after]
                        <sup>Data after running the currencyConditionals sub procedure</sup>

---

¹ <sub>Examples of formatting mask codes can be found at [Number Format Code](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68).</sub>

Comment: Wow, this is very helpful. Thanks. (+1). BTW, I'm thinking a simple method right now. I hope I can post the answer as soon as possible if it works

Answer (score 1):

<s>Though this code is a bit messy, but at least</s> I try what Gary's Student suggests in his answer ([See **EDIT#1**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38306004/3397819)). Suppose that I want to place the original data in column A and the desired formats in column B, then I will:

1. Set Number Format in Column A as Text. To do this, click column A
   heading and look for the **Number** section of the **Home** menu tab
   then click the arrow in the lower right corner of the **Number**
   section and choose Text.
2. Copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) the original data in Notepad then
   click cell A1 and paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>) the data.

Run this code:

```
Sub Keeping_Number_Format_1()
Last_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To Last_Row
   'Determine the number of the decimal places
   Dec_Number = Len(Cells(i, 1)) - InStr(Cells(i, 1), ".")

   'Return the number found in the input string (each cells in column A)
   Cells(i, 2) = Val(Cells(i, 1))

   'Set the data in column B to specific formats
   If Dec_Number = Len(Cells(i, 1)) Then
      Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "0"
   ElseIf Dec_Number = 1 Then
      Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "0.0"
   ElseIf Dec_Number = 2 Then
      Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "0.00"
   ElseIf Dec_Number = 3 Then
      Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "0.000"
   ElseIf Dec_Number = 4 Then
      Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "0.0000"
   'I add these lines just in case the given numbers exceed 4 decimal places.
   'You can add the lines as you wish.
   ElseIf Dec_Number = 5 Then
      Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "0.00000"
   ElseIf Dec_Number = 6 Then
      Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "0.000000"
   End If
Next i
End Sub
```

or one may run the shorter version of the above code. It employs  the [REPT  function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/REPT-function-04c4d778-e712-43b4-9c15-d656582bb061) in Microsoft Excel so that one doesn't need to change the code in the future since it works for data with any number of decimal places.

```
Sub Keeping_Number_Format_2()
Last_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To Last_Row
   Dec_Number = Len(Cells(i, 1)) - InStr(Cells(i, 1), ".")
   Cells(i, 2) = Val(Cells(i, 1))

   If Dec_Number = Len(Cells(i, 1)) Then
      Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "0"
   Else
      Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "0." & WorksheetFunction.Rept("0", Dec_Number)
   End If

Next i
End Sub
```